# Meteor: Session.set, inside Router.route(), is then undefined when used in a 'client' page

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish, router, subscribe

I have an iron router declared in app.js which is in a root 'lib' folder.

```
    Router.route('/editTiki/:_id', function () {

        var params = this.params
        var id = params._id

        Session.set("editTikiID", id)

        this.render("editTikiRoute")

    }, {name:"editTikiRoute"});
```

Then, inside editTiki.js, which is inside the 'client' folder, i have this code:

```
console.log(Session.get("editTikiID"))
// undefined
```

However, it's undefined and don't understand why. I need it to subscribe to the right article:

```
Meteor.subscribe("tikiDBEdit", Session.get("editTikiID"))
```

thx for your insight...

Comment: Out of precaution, can you do a `console.log` in your route to check that the id is defined? Also, don't you need some more `;` in your code?

Comment: Sessions in Meteor are not really like sessions in, say Java.  For one, they are not cookie based, which is noted in their Blog and docs.  As a result, I have noticed in my own code that they have not always acted in a way I think a Session variable should act.  I am not 100% certain, which is why I am doing this as a comment rather than an answer, but I am not seeing how this would work.

Comment: I did the console.log in my route and i get the right value.

Comment: Could you post the entire editTiki.js file? Where exactly is the `Session.get` call? It should probably be in either your template's `created` or `rendered` callbacks. Though it's probably better to let iron:router handle subscriptions for you with it's built in `waitOn` or `subscriptions` options.

Comment: The console.log(Session.get("editTikiID")) is not inside any callback. I'm trying to add it to a simple variable at the top of my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subscribe in your router like here: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#wait-and-ready
or even simpler if you don't want to wait until your subscription is ready:

```
Meteor.subscribe("tikiDBEdit", id);
```

The session variable won't be defined until the route was executed. Any code in your editTiki.js file that is not in a function (like your console.log I guess) will be executed before the session variable is set in your router. Thats just how javascript works.
This means that session variable should be defined in any template helper or the events and rendered functions of your template.